# Orderby modified only for specific post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

Here is my `WP_Query` in which I want to fetch data from multiple custom post types and order them by the modified date:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => array( 'staff-updates', 'employees', 'coreteam', 'developing-updates', 'vacancies', 'recognition', 'page' ),
  'orderby'        => 'modified',
  'posts_per_page' => '10',
  'order'          => 'DESC',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In this I have an exception to fetch only to posts published for custom post type **employees** and not modified in the same query.

Comment: Your question is confusing, please file an [edit] and explain properly what your issue is

Comment: The issue is I have to write a wp_query in which I have to fetch data from different Custom Post Types. The post types are mentioned in the quetion. However, as per the requirement, the modified post has be to retrieved i.e. orderby => modified

Now the issue is; except post type employees the above condition is valid while for post type employees it has to orderby => date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am Afraid that you have to go with `Direct MYSQL` or you can run two `WP_Query()` and then combine them, sort them or sort them with `WP_Query()` then combine them.

Here is an example

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => array( 'staff-updates', 'coreteam',
                           'developing-updates', 'vacancies', 'recognition', 'page' ),
  'orderby'        => 'modified',
  'posts_per_page' => '10',
  'order'          => 'DESC',
);
$the_query_modified = new WP_Query( $args );

$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'employees',
  'orderby'        => 'date', //default to post_date
  'posts_per_page' => '10',
  'order'          => 'DESC',
);
$the_query_published = new WP_Query( $args );

$combined = new WP_Query();
//combining two to one
$combined->posts = array_merge( $the_query_modified->posts, $the_query_published->posts );
```

Now `$combined->posts` will have both. Then do whatever you want. `$combined` might miss few details since it is not direct constructed. In that case you just manipuldate with two queryies( `$the_query_modified`,`$the_query_published` ) directly or go for SQL

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. It works partially! I figured out a patch over this to sort the posts by date_modified (rest all post types) and date_published (employees) and display the latest.

Comment: Ok gald it helped you. Is your patch running single Query or Two Query?